# SP execution time

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, execution-time

I commented all the body of my SP except the declare parameters part. The SP Body is something like below, Note that all other part of body is commented.

```
OUT PO_ERROR            INTEGER,
IN  PI_CURRENT_DATE     INTEGER,
IN  PI_USER_ID          DECIMAL(15),
IN  PI_BID              DECIMAL(15),
IN  PI_AID              DECIMAL(15),
IN  PI_UUID             VARCHAR(36),
IN  PI_XML              XML,
OUT PO_VERSION          INTEGER,
OUT PO_ERROR_MSG        INTEGER,
OUT PO_BID              DECIMAL(15),                               
OUT PO_STEP             INTEGER

SPECIFIC ESPNAME1
RESULT SETS 1
MODIFIES SQL DATA
NOT DETERMINISTIC
NULL CALL
LANGUAGE SQL
BODY: BEGIN

      DECLARE L_SQLCODE         INT         DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE SQLCODE           INTEGER     DEFAULT 0;

      DECLARE L_AID             INTEGER     DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE L_BNO             INTEGER     DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE L_BID             INTEGER     DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
SET L_SQLCODE = SQLCODE;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND  
SET L_SQLCODE = SQLCODE;

SET PO_ERROR = 0; 
SET PO_STEP = 0;
SET PO_ERROR_MSG = 0;
COMMIT;                                        

END BODY
```

**Question:** I run SP with specified input parameters and every time the execution time of SP is in the range of 140ms to 180ms. I think this execution time is much for a SP without body. What is wrong here? Does this time contains get connection time either? If yes, how can I check SP execution time without get connection time?

Note that, I tried deleting `PI_XML` from input parameters, cause I thought maybe the XML input is increasing execution time, but nothing happened and execution time is still in that range.

Comment: Is it possible to relocate the `COMMIT` out of the procedure and instead make the client application or script responsible for committing or rolling back the unit of work? Aside from the possibility that the `COMMIT` is the source of the delay (often due to a suboptimal `COMMITCOUNT` setting on DB2 for LUW), it's not recommended to put a stored procedure in charge of committing a transaction.

Comment: @FredSobotka I checked the execution time without `commit` statement. Know sometimes randomly I have 70ms to 100ms execution time but the other times it's as the same as before. What is this for? Also I used `commit` inside sp because I think It's faster than application side in calculating total execution time (I mean the connection won't be closed until commit finishes), Is that wrong?

Comment: `COMMIT` is only used for finalizing a transaction; it has no impact on whether/when a database connection is closed. If your procedure is being executed by a Java/PHP/.Net application, that application may be closing your database connection automatically, which could cause the DB2 server to deactivate the database if nobody else is connected. To prevent this, issue an `ACTIVATE DATABASE <dbname>` command on the DB2 server to keep the database alive even after the last client application disconnects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot easier to measure the elapsed time of just the stored procedure part if you capture the start and end times inside the procedure itself. One way to accomplish this is to temporarily add a couple of output parameters to it, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
OUT PO_START TIMESTAMP,
OUT PO_END TIMESTAMP )
...
BODY:BEGIN
SET PO_START = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
... -- Rest of the procedure
SET PO_END = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
END BODY
```

In a do-nothing procedure such as the one you're currently testing, I'd be surprised if `PO_START` and `PO_END` differ by more than a handful of milliseconds. The rest of the elapsed time could be caused by any of the following:

- Client opens a database connection and authenticates
- Database was not already activated

Comment: Thanks Fred, I'm going to check and inform about the result